# Racket web server write file error

Tags: racket

I write a web program to write file,and read file.And it failed.

And the program code is following:

```
#lang web-server/insta

(define (start request)
  (index-wrap request))

(define (index-wrap request)
  (define (response-generator embed/url)
    (response/xexpr
      `(html
         (head (title "test"))
         (body
           (h1 "Test Write")
           (form ((action ,(embed/url write-handler)))
                  (input ((type "submit"))))))))

  (define (write-handler request)
    (call-with-output-file "write_file"
                              #:exists 'truncate
                              (lambda (out) (print "hello,world" out)))
  (index-wrap request))
  (send/suspend/dispatch response-generator))
```

And when you click the button,it occurs an error:

```
call-with-output-file: cannot open output file
path: /usr/share/racket/pkgs/web-server-lib/web-server/default-web-root/htdocs/write_file
system error: Permission denied; errno=13
```

And I also write a test program to test the call-with-output-file function,and it write file successful.And my test program code are following:

```
#lang racket

(call-with-output-file "write_other"
                          #:exists 'truncate
                          (lambda (out) (print "hello,racket" out)))
```

So what's the problem about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(define (write-handler request)
    (displayln (list "HERE" (current-directory)))
    (call-with-output-file "write_file"
                              #:exists 'truncate
                              (lambda (out) (print "hello,world" out)))
  (index-wrap request))
  (send/suspend/dispatch response-generator))
```

to see which directory you are trying to write to. I suspect the web-server has changed directory to something else than you expect.

EDIT

Now you know that the path is

```
/usr/share/racket/pkgs/web-server-lib/web-server/default-web-root/htdocs/
```

you have two options.

1. Change the permissions of the folder
2. Start the web-server somewhere else

The easiest is to change the permissions:

```
 cd /usr/share/racket/pkgs/web-server-lib/web-server/default-web-root/
 chmod +w htdocs                 
 sudo chmod +w htdocs
```

Hopefully one of the two last lines work. If not you need to 
google how to set file permissions to write on your OS.

Comment: The path is (HERE /usr/share/racket/pkgs/web-server-lib/web-server/default-web-root/htdocs/)

Comment: how to change the path that the web-server write to?

Comment: @huix I have added some info on file permissions.